# Error while compiling app after reinstalling OSX

Tags: xcode, macos

I have an iOS app in XCode.
It was compiling and running with no error.
After replacing my hard disk and restoring backup from time machine it doesn't compile and prompts this error :

```
ld: can't open file, errno=1 for architecture i386
```

But how can I find which file can't be openned?!

Comment: Have you tried Clean (Command-Shift-K) and then rebuilding?

Comment: Yes, I did. @andyvn22

Comment: I tried clean up another time, now it works, @andyvn22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually errors that make no sense (especially after a huge change like restoring a backup) can be solved with a quick Clean (Command-Shift-K).